# Add Child Node with OmniXML

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe

I'm currently using the OmniXML unit to manipulate my XML files in Delphi XE. I managed to load the XML contents from a file on the disk, now I'd like to add a child node under a specific node element. The new child node will also have an 'id' attribute. May anyone show me how to do so given that the documentation for OmniXML is very poor unfortunately!
I'd also like to save the new XML in another file, may you also clarify how to do so?

Thanks,
Sue

Answer (score 4):

```
uses OmniXMLUtils;

childNode := EnsureNode(parentNode, 'id');
```

Instead of working with raw OmniXML (and OmniXMLUtils, which is an improvement but still pretty basic) you should look at [SimpleStorage](http://www.cromis.net/blog/2010/02/what-is-new-in-simplestorage/) and [GpFluentXML](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2009/10/gpfluentxml-3.html).

Comment: Thank you Gabr... Even though I haven't directly used your suggestion, but it put me on the right track. I used the AppendNode(parentNode, 'id'); instead... Thanks anyway!

Comment: If the answer was the one it solved you problem, then please accept it. This way others will know which answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var
  iDoc, iNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  XMLDocument1.LoadFrom...(...);
  iDoc := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement;

  // Find node where you want child added     
  // and add a new child
  iNode := iDoc.ChildNodes[0].AddChild('NewNode');
  iNode.Attributes['id'] := '2';

  XMLDocument1.SaveTo...(...);
end;
```

BTW, it's not nice to use free, open source software and then complain about it. :) If you don't like the documentation, you can feel free to either buy a commercial product instead or contribute to the author of the open source software, or contribute some work to the documentation to improve it.